# Find where species accumulation curve reaches asymptote

Tags: r, regression

I have used the `specaccum()` command to develop species accumulation curves for my samples.

Here is some example data:

```
site1<-c(0,8,9,7,0,0,0,8,0,7,8,0)
site2<-c(5,0,9,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
site3<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0)
site4<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
site5<-c(5,0,9,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,0,0)
site6<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,0)
site7<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,3)
site8<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
site9<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
site10<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,6)
site11<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0)
site12<-c(5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
site13<-c(5,1,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

species_counts<-rbind(site1,site2,site3,site4,site5,site6,site7,site8,site9,site10,site11,site12,site13)

accum <- specaccum(species_counts, method="random", permutations=100)

plot(accum)
```

In order to ensure I have sampled sufficiently, I need to make sure the curve of the species accumulation plot reaches an asymptote, defined as a slope of <0.3 between the last two points (ei between sites 12 and 13).

```
results <- with(accum, data.frame(sites, richness, sd))
```

Produces this:

```
 sites richness        sd
1      1     3.46 0.9991916
2      2     4.94 1.6625403
3      3     5.94 1.7513054
4      4     7.05 1.6779918
5      5     8.03 1.6542263
6      6     8.74 1.6794660
7      7     9.32 1.5497149
8      8     9.92 1.3534841
9      9    10.51 1.0492422
10    10    11.00 0.8408750
11    11    11.35 0.7017295
12    12    11.67 0.4725816
13    13    12.00 0.0000000
```

I feel like I'm getting there. I could generate an lm with site vs richness and extract the exact slope (tangent?) between sites 12 and 13. Going to search a bit longer here.

Comment: It's important to try to see if you can get it first, then post your code and we can help.

Comment: What is your *specific* problem?

Comment: The vector diff(sites) will always be one (e.g. 3-2; 2-1), isn't it? If I'm right, we can just compute the diff(richness) to get the slope vector? This 0.3 slope threshold is described in some book or article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streamlining your data generation process a little bit:

```
species_counts <- matrix(c(0,8,9,7,0,0,0,8,0,7,8,0,
5,0,9,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,
5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 5,0,9,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,
5,0,9,0,0,0,6,6,0,0,0,0, 5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,3,
5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0, 5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,6, 5,0,9,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,
5,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 5,1,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
byrow=TRUE,nrow=13)
```

Always a good idea to `set.seed()` before running randomization tests (and let us know that `specaccum` is in the `vegan` package):

```
set.seed(101)
library(vegan)
accum <- specaccum(species_counts, method="random", permutations=100)
```

Extract the `richness` and `sites` components from within the returned object and compute `d(richness)/d(sites)` (note that the slope vector is one element shorter than the origin site/richness vectors: be careful if you're trying to match up slopes with particular numbers of sites)

```
(slopes <- with(accum,diff(richness)/diff(sites)))
## [1] 1.45 1.07 0.93 0.91 0.86 0.66 0.65 0.45 0.54 0.39 0.32 0.31
```

In this case, the slope never actually goes below 0.3, so this code for finding the first time that the slope falls below 0.3:

```
which(slopes<0.3)[1]
```

returns `NA`.

Comment: Thank you Ben, this is exactly what I have been looking for! I'll try to be more specific in the future.